# Как получить все названия папок внутри 'Новости/' в Firebase realtime database и записать их в массив в javascript файле (web-приложение)

Tags: javascript, html, база-данных, firebase, realtime

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть я хочу получить все элементы внутри "Новости/", не трогая поля внутри самих значений (Например чтобы в массив записывалось `arr[0] = "Заголовок0" arr[1] = "Заголовок1"` и т.д.)
Предполагаю что это нужно оформить в виде цикла, но не знаю какая именно функция или метод отвечает за получение самого значения этих элементов.

Answer (score 0):

Всё оказалось довольно просто.
В общем я реализовал это таким образом:
Сначала объявил объект, для того чтобы скопировать объект который возвращает firebase.
Затем просто записал все ключи копии объекта в массив.

```
    let CopyObject = {};
            let News = [];
           firebase.database().ref('Новости/').on('value', function(snapshot){
        
                CopyObject = snapshot.val();
                News = Object.keys(CopyObject);
                console.log(News);
});
```